# Python- AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'course_code'

Tags: python, python-2.7, nameerror

Third question for the day. But this one is a brand new program. So now I'm receiving this error (and before you say my code is riddled with errors, I'm expecting that.):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DDeahr/Downloads/College_Student.py", line 58, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/DDeahr/Downloads/College_Student.py", line 46, in main
    Alex.complete_class("English 101", 10)
  File "C:/Users/DDeahr/Downloads/College_Student.py", line 30, in complete_class
    College_Student.complete_class.course_code += self.courses_done
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'course_code'
```

New error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/DDeahr/Downloads/College_Student.py", line 1, in <module>
    class College_Student(object):
  File "C:/Users/DDeahr/Downloads/College_Student.py", line 30, in College_Student
    course_code = staticmethod(course_code)
NameError: name 'course_code' is not defined
```

Here's my code:

```
class College_Student(object):
    total = 0
    enrolled = []

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, id_num, courses_done, credit_hrs):
        self = self
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.id_num = id_num
        self.courses_done = [],
        self.credit_hrs = credit_hrs

    def __str__(self):
        first_name = self.first_name
        last_name = self.last_name
        id_num = self.id_num
        courses_done = self.courses_done
        credit_hrs = self.credit_hrs
        College_Student.total += 1
        College_Student.enrolled += self.last_name
        College_Student.enrolled.sort()
        return "First Name: %s\nLast Name: %s\nID Number: %s\nCourses Finished: %s\nCredit Hours: %s\n" % (self.first_name, self.last_name, self.id_num, self.courses_done, self.credit_hrs)

    def complete_class(self,course_code,student_credit_hrs):
        self.credit_hrs += student_credit_hrs
        self.courses_done = []
        College_Student.complete_class.course_code += self.courses_done
        return "Student with ID number: %s has finished course %s which is %s credit hours." % (self.id_num, self.course_code, self.student_credit_hours)

    def can_grad(self):
        if self.credit_hrs >= 120:
            return "Student with ID number: %s can now graduate." % (self.id_num)
        else:
            return "Student with ID number: %s cannot graduate yet." % (self.id_num)

def main():
    print "Creating student John"
    John = College_Student("John", "Appleseed", 111111, None, 20)
    print John
    print "Creating student Alex"
    Alex = College_Student("Alex", "Trannon", 222222, None, 30)
    print Alex
    Alex.complete_class("English 101", 10)
    Alex.complete_class("Mathmatics 102", 20)
    Alex.complete_class("Computer Sciences 208", 60)
    John.complete_class("Psychology 5005", 40)
    John.complete_class("English 108.365", 2)
    John.complete_class("Chinese 101", 10)
    John.complete_class("Computer Sciences 30", 28)
    Alex.can_grad()
    John.can_grad()
    print total
    print enrolled

main()
```

Any and all help is much appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: Yep, it's an instance method and it doesn't have any attributes. What exactly are you trying to do? Why is `courses_done` a single-element tuple containing a list? Why is some of the initialisation done in `__str__`?

Comment: `College_Student.complete_class` is a function.  `College_Student.complete_class.course_code` is an invalid lookup against the function.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that line?

Comment: It doesn't look like you've updated your code to match the new error you have. Really, though, what are you trying to do with that line? We're not being jerks, we seriously can't figure out what you attempted there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do  - change :

```
College_Student.complete_class.course_code += self.courses_done
```

to

```
self.courses.done.append(course_code) -
```

note:

```
self.courses.done += self.course_code
```

also works but as pointed out by @jonsharpe is less explicit.

Also :

1. in complete_class - don't set self.courses_done to [] - do that in **init** - where it is is at the moment it will reset the students courses list each time they complete a course
2. It is bad form to change the instance variables in the **str** method - that method should simply be used to provide a text representation of that student - as you have it coded it it seems to make changes, for no obvious reason.

Comment: It should be `courses_done`, and you `append` to lists.

Comment: This is what appeared to work... sorry I didn't actually explain the problem.

Comment: @jonsharpe - i agree you should use append (as it is explicit), but "+=" also works on lists. I have modified my answer to use append

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted, since the OP clearly accepted it :-(